# What is the universal method to escape keywords in SQL query?

Tags: sql, jdbc

If my query is

```
SELECT from FROM myTable;
```

How can I escape column name 'from'.

**I need a way which is applicable to Oracle, MySQL, Teradata and all other systems**

Will

```
SELECT myTable.from FROM mytable;
```

work on all systems?

Comment: There is no "universal" method (although there are ANSI standard ways).  Just don't use column names that are keywords and you won't have the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The SQL standard is pretty clear: reserved keywords can only be used when they are enclosed in double quotes:

```
select "FROM" from mytable;
```

Note that a quoted identifier are also case **sensitive**. `"Foo"` and `"FOO"` are two different names! (whereas `Foo` and `FOO` are the same names in standard SQL and most DBMS)

---

> *I need a way which is applicable to Oracle, MySQL, Teradata and all other systems*

Postgres, Oracle, DB2 (LUW), Firebird, Ingres, HSQLDB, H2, Vertica, HANA and Teradata comply with the standard out of the box.

MySQL needs to convinced to respect the standard by setting `sql-mode` to `ANSI` or at least `ANSI_QUOTES`.

For SQL Server the option `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` needs to be set to `on`.

For Informix you need to set `DELIMIDENT` to `y` when connecting through JDBC

---

But in general you should **really** avoid the need to use quoted identifiers. Typically you will get in trouble sooner or later by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Universal method??? not sure about any such but double quote `""` is ANSI standard other than that every RDBMS has some specific way of doing so. Moreover you don't need any such universal way if you refrain yourself from using reserve word or keyword for table or column name .. as already suggested in comment